# Change new text view inside of a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-linearlayout

I built a linear layout inside of a dialog , the problem here that i want to change the TextView of this layout but i don't know how ! ,, any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you would do it with a normal view.

```
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
text.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: it crashes !! i think because of (setContentView),  i am using  the id from another layout that the (setContentView) is using !